# Omit empty array from generic function paramater call in typescript

Tags: typescript, generics

I am looking for a way to not provide an empty array for a generic function `Parameter<F>`-typed parameter when `F` does not receive parameters.
The following working example shows the current state

```
type A<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
    shouldPrintHello: boolean;
    params: Parameters<F>;
};

const wrappingFunction = <F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(sentFunction: F, defaultParams: A<F>) => {
    const innterFunction = (...args: Parameters<F>) => {
        if (defaultParams.shouldPrintHello) console.log("hello");
        sentFunction(args);
        return;
    };

    const defaultValue = sentFunction(defaultParams);
    return innterFunction;
};

const f1 = wrappingFunction(
    (arg0: string) => {
        return;
    },
    { shouldPrintHello: true, params: ["defaultString"] }
);

const f2 = wrappingFunction(
    () => {
        return;
    },
    { shouldPrintHello: true, params: [] }
);

f1("a string");
f2();
```

Desired (pseudo) code changes:

```
type A<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
    shouldPrintHello: boolean;
    params: Parameters<F> === [] ? undefined : Parameters<F>;
};

const f2 = wrappingFunction(
    () => {
        return;
    },
    { shouldPrintHello: true }
);

f2();
```

Comment: Have you checked out the `extends` keyword?

Comment: yes, but I don't see how it can be of use here sadly

Comment: How? It functions very similarly to equality. Although it's not "equality" but more of "<:", it still works here.

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WY343N) meet your needs? If so I could write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?  (Please say @jcalz in your comment to notify me)

Comment: @jcalz thank you but this approach doesn't work for me. I'm trying to implement it as follows but without success: [link](https://tsplay.dev/NrXnVW)

Comment: That's a separate issue having to do with *generic* conditional types.  I'd say it's out of scope for your question as asked, but if you care about that, please [edit] the code in the question to demonstrate that use case.  (For that issue, the compiler can't really follow such logic, so I'd just use a type assertion like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w8xEMw).)  Let me know (and mention @jcalz) how you'd like to proceed here.

Comment: @jcalz thank you! I decided to stick with the empty array over your suggestion but your solution is great, please post it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: If I answer the question, I will post [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/WY343N) and not [this solution](https://tsplay.dev/w8xEMw) because the latter is addressing something only mentioned in a comment and not the question itself.  Does that work for you or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: @jcalz you are correct, the first solution is a better answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no built-in way to express that a property is optional if and only if some condition holds of its value, so if you want a type like that you have to write it  yourself as a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html):

```
type OptionalParamsIfAllowedToBeEmpty<P> =
  [] extends P ? { params?: P } : { params: P }
```

And then you can [intersect](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) it into the rest of your type definition:

```
type A<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
  shouldPrintHello: boolean;
} & OptionalParamsIfAllowedToBeEmpty<Parameters<F>>;

declare const wrappingFunction: <F extends (...args: any[]) => any>(
  sentFunction: F,
  defaultParams: A<F>) => (...args: Parameters<F>) => void
```

Let's test it out.  First, let's make sure it behaves as desired for functions with at least one required parameter:

```
wrappingFunction(
  (arg0: string) => {
    return;
  },
  { shouldPrintHello: true, params: ["defaultString"] }
);    

wrappingFunction(
  (arg0: string) => {
    return;
  },
  { shouldPrintHello: true } // error! missing params
);
```

Looks good, `params` is not optional.  Then let's test it for functions without any parameters:

```
wrappingFunction(
  () => {
    return;
  },
  { shouldPrintHello: true }
);

wrappingFunction(
  () => {
    return;
  },
  { shouldPrintHello: true, params: [] } // okay
);

wrappingFunction(
  () => {
    return;
  },
  { shouldPrintHello: true, params: undefined } // okay
);

wrappingFunction(
  () => {
    return;
  },
  { shouldPrintHello: true, params: ["defaultString"] } // error
);
```

Also looks good; you can leave out `params`, or pass in `undefined` or an empty array `[]`, but it won't let you pass in the wrong parameters.  Finally, let's see how it behaves with a function with parameters that are all optional:

```
function f(x?: string) { }
wrappingFunction(f, { shouldPrintHello: false }) // okay
wrappingFunction(f, { shouldPrintHello: false, params: ["abc"] }) // okay
```

That's also what you want, I think.  Since you can call `f()`, you shouldn't be *required* to pass in `params` in `wrappingFunction`, but since you can also call `f("abc")`, you should be *allowed* to pass in `params` as `["abc"]`.  This is an important difference between the `[] extends P` check in `OptionalParamsIfAllowedToBeEmpty<P>` and a seemingly similar `P extends []` check; if `P` is `[x?: string]`, then `[] extends [x?: string]` is true, but `[x?: string] extends []` is false.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9#code/C4TwDgpgBA8mwEsD2A7AhgGwApoE5oFsBnASQDMBRA+EAHiwD4oBeAWACgooBtAXSggAPYBBQATIlCxQA-FADeUMHkJEZALilQAvlE2Ll+YpunaOHUJCgBBWgDEBw0RKgAKAHSe8AcyKa0KCB8AJQsTAEgTMwKHFxEABZIAK4YYli4CCjAABIQGBhImgBGSEgYEAEA3By6AGSw8Mjo2CrE5FQ09K0QIrhE9gwM1ewcYhAAxhh40OOoRMBQAO74YGCZ3nZJKOOIqJr2jiLikh5euL7+gSFhUBEMrrFQRKLAm9u7KJp2ADSPY2RoFLAHBGPw2AahZhMU7uHxgkGEHoQPoQm4ANyQCDE5nYyzQq3Wbx2TQenDcPgADJp5hkUN5IUx5I8uLgeklcChhlxtL8yYoEslUulMjk8gVNMBcEkIN8lK0wdwAET-QEYYAAZUl60V-DM7GCwxxeIJdKJH1JXFclOpWrpDJiZJZbI5XJ0vK4-MSKTStNF+UKUEl0p0UAA9KGBLhcEhcABCKAEBBEIjrOWgjgGnEcY1rU1bYmoC1ue1Mx1QVnAdmcx48x6ewU+kW5f0SqXQPWZka4la5jb582PVwl5nl53Vsm1vlPL1C33N8WBtuywyqTR8EPhqBIADWaBAGcN3fxvbNJMHw7LFarrsnHunDeFWXnAaDMrTq6gW3+mQgYg3EZ3PcDyNHtCX7M8ySHG5Sy4J1KxdGt3QUe9vUfP0F1fZd5TXZUIABIFNVpbwdX-SNo1wYCuxxMhwNQKAyFcQQNCeW16WQvUczA94STIWV61QucxQDAEMGeHRQk3QD9yPE0+24wteOQgUBKbITNBE54sNBHC0CKcYSO0CSAN3EAgA)

Answer (score 0):

Don't be afraid to use `extends` to check for "equality":

```
type A<F extends (...args: any[]) => any> = {
    shouldPrintHello: boolean;
    params: Parameters<F> extends [] ? undefined : Parameters<F>;
};
```

Alternatively, you can check the length:

```
params: Parameters<F>["length"] extends 0 ? undefined : Parameters<F>;
```

Comment: Thanks, but after applying your suggestion I still must use 
`{ shouldPrintHello: true, params: undefined }`